# Asking extra password when using scp

Tags: bash, ssh, scp, tty

I'm not sure if I should be asking this here or in Server Fault, feel free to flag the question and migrate it if necessary.

I have some servers which I would like to add an extra security layer. Actually we are using key authentication with passphrase.

We bought some Yubikeys (OTP password generator) that I would like to use. I created a system that validates the Yubikey and that the owner of the Yubikey is authorized to login. In order to use this system I created the `~/.ssh/rc` where I ask the user to press the Yubikey and then I use a remote server to validate it.

So far so good, it works perfectly when trying to login via ssh. Here comes the problem: when I try to `scp` to a server that has this extra protection it throws the following error:

```
/dev/tty: No such device or address
```

The error is thrown by the line where I ask the user to enter the OTP:

```
read -sp "Press your Yubikey..." OTP < /dev/tty
```

This doesn't happen when I `ssh` from one server to another that has this extra protection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scp` doesn't start an interactive session so there isn't a terminal to connect to (and so no `/dev/tty` to read from).

You need to detect that and not try to read from it in that case.

That being said this is likely the wrong way to have gone about doing this. `ssh` is most likely configured on your system to use `pam` and there is a `pam` module for `yubikey` that can be used to use a `yubikey` as part of the `ssh` authentication for an account. See https://developers.yubico.com/yubico-pam/ for the basics.

Their configuration uses the `yubikey` as the only authentication you will need to configure `pam` slightly differently to get it to be an additional piece of required login information instead. (Assuming, of course, that you want this to work for the `scp` case instead of just skipping it for the `scp` case.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The only reason why I didn't use the `pam` module is because in addition to validate the yubikey I also use a database to check if the yubikey owner has permission to login. Maybe I can modificate the para module?

Comment: I would look for a pam module for that bit too. This is sort of the point of the pam stack idea. Is this db check separate from having a system account? Could you leverage system accounts (provisioned from the db) for this instead? This might also be something that `nsswitch.conf`/etc. might be useful for potentially.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Etan, you really should just use PAM for this.

Note that you don't have to ask for the user to press the Yubikey either.  The `pam_yubico.so` module will pass through anything you type before the challenge response to the next module in the PAM stack.  Look at the `try_first_pass` flag in `pam_unix(8)` for instance.

Just type the password, *don't press enter*, then press the Yubikey.

You can implement your own module to do the database check.  Writing PAM modules isn't that hard.

Something like this in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

```
# auth
auth        requisite   /usr/local/lib/security/pam_yubico.so id=[yours] key=[yours] authfile=/etc/yubikey_mappings
auth        required    pam_unix.so     no_warn try_first_pass
```

Try logging in:

```
% slogin hogfather
YubiKey for `philip': [password][yubikey]
Last login: Thu Mar  5 01:13:55 2015 from twoflower.trouble.is
```

Comment: If I write my own PAM module, will it also work in non interactive sessions? I ask because I already have it working and it simply doesn't ask for the yubikey when it is not an interactive session. If it works with non interactive sessions I will try to write my own PAM module.

Comment: Sure.  If your PAM module only checks in a file or a database if some flag is set, and doesn't need user input, it can be completely non-interactive. A nice example of a module that does something similar to what you want would be [`pam_opieaccess.so`](http://svn.freebsd.org/base/head/lib/libpam/modules/pam_opieaccess/pam_opieaccess.c)

Answer (score 0):

OK, you want the yubikey authentication plus an authorization, that checks, whether the user is allowed to login at this server.

You might want to take a look at [privacyIDEA](http://privacyidea.org).
This is an OTP authentication backend. You can even initialize your yubikeys if you like to. Use pam_radius to forward the auth request to privacyIDEA. (no hassle with scp).

privacyIDEA can

1. check the OTP value of the yubikey AND
2. use policies to check, if the user is allowed to login on that machine with this token type or token serial number. see [readthedocs](http://privacyidea.readthedocs.org/en/latest/policies/authorization.html#authorization-policies)